# Drupal 8 - how do I extract the URL path from node title

Tags: theming

I can print title of my `content-type` using `{{ fields.title.content }}`. and it renders like `<a href='...'>Title of the content</a>`. I have created a `View` (view mode: field) and showing a list of available products on that page. To customize look and feel of the page I copied `views-view-fields.html.twig` file from `core/themes/stable/template/views` under my theme's template directory and customized it the following way.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box-gray-border-only border-radius-5 padd-all-5">
        {{ fields.field_product_image.content }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="item-list-title-anchor margin-auto larger">{{ fields.title.content }}</h3>
    <p class="margin-t10 small">{{ fields.field_product_summary.content|striptags|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') }}</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sx-12 text-right">
        <span>{{ fields.field_category.content }}</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <span><b class="text-red">Price: {{ fields.field_product_price.content }}</b></span>&nbsp;
        <a title="{{ fields.content.title }}" class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : node.id}) }}">View &raquo;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="margin-t20"></div>
<hr />
```

The title itself is linked to product's page. But I have an additional View button which I want to link to the product page separately as well. In order to accomplish the same I tried to extract the `URL` part from the `title` with `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : node.id}) }}`. But it gives me the following error message.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "node" for route "entity.node.canonical" must match "\d+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL. in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 193 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator.php).

I am referring to this article:
https://chromatichq.com/blog/creating-links-within-twig-templates-using-path-and-url

What I did wrong?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I used `{{ dump(fields.title.content) }}` to see if I the `URL` could be accessible, but there was nothing like it.

Comment: Are you using drupal commerce 8.x-2.x-dev or are your products just nodes?

Comment: I am using Drupal 8.2.3. I am on Windows. Downloaded 8.2.3 from Acqiua Dev Desktop software.

Comment: So try {{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}. Also use kint or devel_dump for twig debug

Comment: Awesome @AndrewNim. +1. You made my night!

Comment: If you don't mind i will add my answer for you to mark as right.

Comment: Of course! Please do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}`. Also it is better to use `kint` or `devel_dump` for twig debug.

Comment: I tried `{{ dump(fields.title.content) }}` but it did not give me enough information. Only gave this (please note: I have twig debug enabled)
`object(Drupal\Core\Render\Markup)#1278 (1) { ["string":protected]=> string(366) " <!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' --> <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' --> <a href="/product/lenovo-vibe-k5-plus-3-gb-dark-grey-16-gb" hreflang="en">Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus 3 GB (Dark Grey, 16 GB)</a> <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view-field.html.twig' --> " }`

Comment: For you to study https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-compiled-twig-templates and https://drupalize.me/blog/201405/lets-debug-twig-drupal-8

Comment: Thank you once again for your enormous help! I will go through those articles :)